# How to select column values where all values of another column are equal to something?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with columns `category_id` and `is_required` (among others), and I wish to select all values of `category_id` where **all records** have `is_required = 0`.

Something like `SELECT category_id FROM table WHERE ALL is_required = 0`

**Edit:** Another way of phrasing it - I need to select only those `category_id` values which **never** have `is_required = 1` in the entire table

Comment: I don't get your question. Have you got two tables you want to join? Or is it just the word "ALL" which is too much in your sql-statement?

Comment: My goal is to ONLY select those rows where the category_id value is only ever found within records that have is_required = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can readily do this with `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.category_id = t.category_id and
                        (t2.is_required <> 0 or t2.is_required is null)
                 );
```

If you only want the *category ids*, then aggregation might produce more reasonable results:

```
select category_id
from table t
group by category_id
having sum(t.is_required <> 0 or t.is_required is null) = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, your second suggestion worked. Well, almost, I had to rewrite t2 to t ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you need?

```
select t1.category_id from `table` t1 left join `table` t2  on t1.category_id =t2.category_id and t1.is_required = 0 and t2.is_required = 1 where t2.category_id is null.
```

Comment: Nope, that would give me all records with a given category_id which have is_required = 0 somewhere in the table. I need to make sure that there are no is_required = 1 with that category_id